# ListView: Scroll to an item at the top of the ListView (and keep it there)?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, runnable

I have a ListView with a significant number of items on it. I would like to figure out a way to get it to scroll to a certain position, but have that position be at the very top of the view.

The other issue is that the ListView gets invalidated and re-drawn at some point *after* this happens and I need it to return to this position when it is re-drawn.

I have tried smoothScrollToPosition, but this only brings the item into the view, and does not place it at the top. I have tried scrollTo(x,y) but I don't know the exact y-position of the item in the view. I have tried setSelection and setSelectionFromTop, but the selection gets reset when the view is invalidated. I have also tried all of these things within a post(Runnable) call, with no luck.

Here is the solution I have at the moment, which is awful.

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      listView.smoothScrollToPosition(10000);
      listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
    }
  });
```

This forces it to scroll down to the bottom and scroll back up until the item at the specified position comes into the view, which has the effect of placing it at the top. Fortunately, the animation only goes so far as to scroll from the top to the end position, so it doesn't actually play out scrolling to the bottom and then back up. However, this solution is slow, hacky, and just generally awful. Does anyone have a better one?